# How do I sum the same cell from dynamic sheets in another cell in master sheet using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have a workbook with a master sheet (called Data Total) and then multiple other sheets with data named with by the date of the data (e.g "05.23.19"). I get new data every day, so I add a new sheet every day. I would like to sum say, cell F3, from every sheet of the workbook into cell A1.

I'm new to vba so I'm learning as I'm trying. I tried a For Each loop, but got hit back with error messages each time saying for exemple "no object found". I know the code below is wrong, but I was thinking od doing something along the lines of this:

```
Sub SumSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisActiveWorkbook

'select cell F3 in every sheet (exept the master sheet "Data Total" and sum them in cell A1'
```

Comment: Change `ThisActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` and then try to write the code, when you experience a problem, return and ask SO a question concerning the error you are receiving and what line the error is on.

Comment: @Jules-Henri Revault Please mark below answer as correct so the thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sum the totals in cell F3 of every sheet within the workbook (except Data Total) and then set the total on the Data Total worksheet in cell A1.

```
Sub SumSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sumTotal As Double

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> "Data Total" Then
        sumTotal = sumTotal + ws.Range("F3").Value
    End If

Next

Sheets("Data Total").Range("A1").Value = sumTotal

End Sub
```